# best indexes for this query for getting messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which gets the newest message received for each user ("inbox" query) :

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE msg.*, msg.id as msg_id, t2.count_msgs, usr.gender,  usr.id,
            msg.senderid as refuid from mailbox msg
inner join (select senderid,max(id) as last_msg_id,count(id) as count_msgs from mailbox where recipientid='893720' and owner='893720' and folder='inbox' group by senderid) t2 on 
t2.senderid = msg.senderid and t2.last_msg_id = msg.id
left join user usr on usr.id = msg.senderid
 where recipientid = '893720' order by msg.sendtime desc;
```

I currently have an index on mailbox (owner,folder,senderid). Explain output :

[image]

any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE msg.*, msg.id as msg_id, t2.count_msgs, usr.gender,  usr.id,
        msg.senderid as refuid
from mailbox msg inner join
     (select senderid, max(id) as last_msg_id, count(id) as count_msgs 
      from mailbox
      where recipientid = '893720' and owner = '893720' and folder = 'inbox'
      group by senderid
     ) t2
     on t2.senderid = msg.senderid and t2.last_msg_id = msg.id left join
     user usr
     on usr.id = msg.senderid
where msg.recipientid = '893720'
order by msg.sendtime desc;
```

The best indexes for this version of the query are:  `mailbox(recipientid, owner, folder, senderid, id)`, mailbox(senderid, id)`, and`user(id)`.

The first index is a covering index for the subquery (meaning it contains the columns).  The keys are ordered by the `where` clause.  The second and third are needed for the `join`s.  The third probably already exists.

Note if the `recipientid` and `owner` are really numbers, then don't use single quotes for the values.  Sometimes, using the wrong types can confuse SQL optimizers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try those indexes, can you pls explain the rationale behind them?

Comment: Thanks I have tested with the indexes, however the first line of the explain is still displaying (Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort) - and the query is still being logged in the slow query (not for being slow but for not using indexes fully)

Comment: @SherifBuzz . . . As you have written the query, there is probably no way to avoid the file sort for the final `order by`.  Your best performance is to get the result set for the sort as speedily as possible.